# Cannot create ActiveX Component - Windows Server 2016 + Excel 2016 32bits

Tags: vba

I have a dll Library that works nice with Windows Server 2008/Excel 2013 32 bits, but fails with Windows Server 2016 + Excel 2016 32 bits, showing the following message: Cannot Create Active Component (I can compile the VBA code test without error).

I created a VB6 EXE app to test that dll and it worked nice on WinServer 2016.

Many thanks for any kind of help.

Best regards,